# c++ object to string

Tags: c++, ios, gdb

I'd like to output the contents of a C++ object (happens to be a circular buffer implementation) to a string for logging purposes. I was planning on doing this by hand, but then noticed that running print-object on my object in the GDB debugger gives me a lovely formatted output, like this:

```
(gdb) print audioDebugMessageQueue
$1 = {
  writePointer = 1, 
  readPointer = 0, 
  keys = {{
      samples = {0.155292124, 0.106764726}, 
      timeStamp = 1322767911, 
      numFrames = 1024
    }, {
      samples = {0, 0}, 
      timeStamp = 0, 
      numFrames = 0
    }, {
      samples = {0, 0}, 
      timeStamp = 0, 
      numFrames = 0
    }, {
      samples = {0, 0}, 
      timeStamp = 0, 
      numFrames = 0
    }, {
      samples = {0, 0}, 
      timeStamp = 0, 
      numFrames = 0
    }, {
      samples = {0, 0}, 
      timeStamp = 0, 
      numFrames = 0
    }, {
      samples = {0, 0}, 
      timeStamp = 0, 
      numFrames = 0
    }, {
      samples = {0, 0}, 
      timeStamp = 0, 
      numFrames = 0
    }, {
      samples = {0, 0}, 
      timeStamp = 0, 
      numFrames = 0
    }, {
      samples = {0, 0}, 
      timeStamp = 0, 
      numFrames = 0
    }}
}
```

If GDB can access a pretty dump of my object, I figure I probably can too. But how? I'm on iOS, by the way.

Comment: Well, this is implemented in GDB, it's interpretation of the binary code of the exe file. I'm pretty sure you can't use this in your C++ program, unless you find that piece of code in GDB's source and "steal" it :? But still, +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why gdb can give you this nice output is that if instructed to (the `-g` option to gcc), the compiler generates, in addition to the normal code, some extra information about how to interpret the binary structures in your program. The debugger reads and interprets this extra information, and then when you print an object, it uses it to output your object. Note that if you don't include debugging information in your files (i.e. if you don't use `-g`), then gdb cannot give you such nice prints even if you tell it exactly where that variable lives (another information the debugging information contains).

Now you could certainly write code to read that debugging information for your program and then use that to display the classes (or, if the licensing allows it, even use existing code for it). However unless you are using it for *very* many different types (and are OK with the restriction that you have to compile with debugging information, which may aid people in reverse-engineering your code) it is almost certainly easier to just write the printing code by hand.

Yet another option would of course be to require gdb to be installed, and to call it from your program in order to generate the output. It's probably not what you would want to do, however (it would however work around any licensing issues).

Comment: If you wanted to get really crazy, you could write a program that would codegen stream insertion operators for your types based on the debugging information, rather like the serpent eating its own tail. If someone were to actually do this I would heartily congratulate them and then throw up a little in my mouth.

Answer (score 1):

Write stream insertion operators for each of the classes in your class, then for your class itself, then for the container.

Given

```
class C {
   public: 
   int a;
   sometype b;

}

typedef std::vector< C > Cvector;
```

you'd want something like:

```
template<class E, class T>
std::basic_ostream<E,T> &operator <<( std::basic_ostream<E,T> &s, const sometype & a ) { /* ... */ }

template<class E, class T>
std::basic_ostream<E,T> &operator <<( std::basic_ostream<E,T> &s, const C& a_c ) 
{
     s << std::hex << std::setw(8) << a_c.a << std::endl
       << a_c.b;
}

template<class E, class T>
std::basic_ostream<E,T> &operator <<( std::basic_ostream<E,T> &s, const Cvector & cvec  ) 
{
     for ( iterator i = cvec.begin(); i != cvec.end(); ++i )
          s << *i << std::endl;
}
```

[Consider this pseudo code...]